# Is there a lightweight, all purpose validation library/DSL for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, database, validation, testing

I'm doing a lot of bulk data-validation on various kinds of data sources and I find myself writing such boilerplate code:

```
if summed_payments != row['Total']
  raise "The sum of the payments, #{summed_payments} != #{row['Total']}"
end
```

I was wondering if there was a way to apply a DSL, like Minitest, but to use it for purposes that didn't involve application testing? For example, finding and logging errors during a bulk data import and validation script...it's a quick-and-dirty script that I don't want to have to write a test suite for, but that I want to do some various kinds of validation upon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think standalone ActiveModel should be good for this.

Watch this railscast for more information: http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model

Comment: I was just about to type, "Even without a database" and then thought I should click through first...Thank you!

Comment: Yup. Just watch that video or read this http://asciicasts.com/episodes/193-tableless-model.

Answer (score 0):

If you like you can check out http://rubygems.org/gems/validates_simple which is a gem for doing simple validation of hashes trying to mimic the interface of the active model validation methods.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but our [Veto](https://github.com/kodio/veto) gem is likely what you're looking for: https://github.com/kodio/veto

Standalone validation of plain old ruby object, without dependencies.